# How to add weekly timedeltas with regards to daylight saving timezones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, dst, timedelta

I want to add or subtract weeks (or days or month or years) to localized datetime objects. The problem is, that the naive approach will result in 1 hour shifts due to daylight saving timezones.

2014-03-27 12:00 is right before the switch from winter to summer time. If I add a timedelta of one week to this date localized in timezone Europe/Berlin for example, the result will be 2014-04-03 13:00. I would like to have the same hour of day, 2014-04-03 12:00. I found a solution:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
my_tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Berlin")

def add_relativedelta(date, delta):
    """
    Adds the given timedelta to the given date. Shifts in timezone offsets
    will be removed.
    """
    tz = date.tzinfo
    result = tz.normalize(date + delta)
    if result.utcoffset() != date.utcoffset():
        result = tz.normalize(date.utcoffset() - result.utcoffset() + result)
    return result

date = my_tz.localize(datetime(year=2014, month=3, day=27, hour=12, minute=0))
print """{} Original localized date (winter time)
{} One week later (summer time)
{} Date one week later preserving hour of day (summer time)""".format(date,
                     my_tz.normalize(date + timedelta(days=7)),
                     add_relativedelta(date, timedelta(days=7)))


2014-03-27 12:00:00+01:00 Original localized date (winter time)
2014-04-03 13:00:00+02:00 One week later (summer time)
2014-04-03 12:00:00+02:00 Date one week later preserving hour of day (summer time)
```

I was wondering if there is more generic/better solution. Are there any libraries that could solve this? This seems to be a pretty common issue.

Comment: related; if you have to *include* the DST change: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63579796/10197418

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`timedelta(days=7)` means 7 days, as in `7*24` hours - not "solar days".
If you add 7 days to a timezone-aware datetime, you'll obtain a datetime that is 7 days later - independently of how that datetime is **represented** in the  timezone.

It seems what you really want is to apply the delta to the time you specified, *ignoring* timezone details. Notice the difference:

```
In [13]: print my_tz.normalize( my_tz.localize( dt ) + delta )
2014-04-03 13:00:00+02:00

In [14]: print my_tz.normalize( my_tz.localize( dt + delta ) )
2014-04-03 12:00:00+02:00
```

So, if possible, apply the deltas to the datetimes before they are localized.

Answer (score 3):

I use this simple code without the need for other libraries:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

tz = timezone('Europe/Berlin')
dt = tz.localize(datetime(2014, 3, 27, 12))

week_naive = datetime.combine(dt.date() + timedelta(days=7), dt.time())
week_local = dt.tzinfo.localize(week_naive)

print(dt, "Original datetime")
print(week_local, "Next week datetime")
```

Outputs:

```
2014-03-27 12:00:00+01:00 Original datetime
2014-04-03 12:00:00+02:00 Next week datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the start and end of a week from a given date and I ran into this issue. I was able to achieve a DST-aware timedelta using the [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io) package. Here's how I did it:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime

import arrow


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Week:
    start: datetime
    end: datetime


def get_week_range(dt: datetime, tz: str) -> Week:
    """Returns Week instance with localized, time-aware start and end datetimes"""
    dt = arrow.get(dt, tz)
    start = dt.shift(days=-dt.weekday())
    end = start.shift(days=7).shift(seconds=-1)

    return Week(start=start, end=end)


>>> get_week_range(datetime(2020, 10, 27), "America/Chicago")
Week(start=<Arrow [2020-10-26T00:00:00-05:00]>, end=<Arrow [2020-11-01T23:59:59-06:00]>)
```

Notice how the returned end date in this example is correctly adjusted to `-06:00` offset since daylight savings ends on 11/1 at 2am for `America/Chicago` time zone.