# Find timedelta difference with DST hours (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, dst

Given two datetimes such as `2020-01-01 00:00:00` and `2020-04-01 00:00:00`, I want to get the timedelta between the two dates in terms of number of hours **with any addition/subtraction due to daylight saving time**. I am not sure how I can proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Python's `timedelta` gives you wall-time difference for aware datetime objects (those that have a time zone attached) - not absolute time (in a physical sense; with the second as [SI unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units)).

To get a "DST aware" timedelta, first make sure the datetime objects are localized to a certain time zone (that has the DST). Then, you take into account the UTC offset of the two datetime objects; for example like

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import gettz

t0, t1 = "2020-03-07 00:00:00", "2020-03-09 00:00:00"
# to datetime object
t0, t1 = datetime.fromisoformat(t0), datetime.fromisoformat(t1)
# set appropriate timezone
tzone = gettz("US/Eastern")
t0, t1 = t0.replace(tzinfo=tzone), t1.replace(tzinfo=tzone)
# check if UTC offset changed
utcdelta = t1.utcoffset() - t0.utcoffset()
# now calculate the timedelta
td = t1 - t0 - utcdelta
print(td)
# 1 day, 23:00:00
```

For further reading, I recommend the [Semantics of timezone-aware datetime arithmetic](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html) blog post by Paul Ganssle.

Comment: Thanks FObersteiner, this worked great for me!

Later on I found that converting to a DST-free timezone such as UTC will also ensure an absolute delta: print(t1.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc) - t0.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc))

Comment: @JimmyHe great if this was helpful. And yes, conversion to UTC is a way to go if you want absolute difference directly without having to take into account the UTC offsets as I show in the answer. Btw. I should also suggest to use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) from the standard library (Python 3.9). Same semantics, but one dependency removed :)